# Как пройти по списку с последующим удалением элементов?

Tags: python

Всем привет!
Есть следующий код:

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for i in some_list:
    print(i)
    some_list.remove(i)
```

Принтует, конечно же:

1
3
5
7
9

Из за того, с каждой итерацией i увеличивается, а элементы списка сдвигаются.
Каким образом можно решить эту проблему, чтобы вывелись и потом последовательно удалились все элементы?

Comment: Ну так сначала в 1 цикле выводите, а потом во 2 удаляйте ..

Comment: Зачем это надо?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy уж не знаю практического применения, но это небольшая часть задания по алгоритмам в университете.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin мы идем по списку, i = 0. remove удаляет элемент, и второй элемент списка становится на позицию 0. Но, поскольку итерация продолжается, цикл видит элемент 3 (i = 1), а 2 (i = 0 после удаления 1)пропускает

Answer (score 2):

```py
some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
while some_list:
    print(
        some_list.pop(0)
    )
```

Comment: `pop` выглядит самым лаконичным решением. А вот конструкция `for _ in range(len(some_list)):` выглядит излишне громоздкой. Почему не `while some_list:`?

Comment: @АлексейР, не могу не согласиться.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(*a, sep='\n')
a[:] = []
```